# GRASS fails to start

Tags: grass

I get the following error when trying to start grass for the first time

```
$ grass -text
ERROR: Unable to start GRASS GIS. You have the choice to:
 - Launch the graphical user interface with the '-gui' switch
     grass74 -gui
 - Launch with path to the location/mapset as an argument
     grass74 /path/to/location/mapset`
 - Create a location with '-c' and launch in its PERMANENT mapset
     grass74 -c EPSG:number /path/to/location
     grass74 -c geofile /path/to/location
 - Create manually the GISRC file (/home/nomon/.grass7/rc)
 - Use '--help' for further options
     grass74 --help
See also: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/helptext.html
Exiting...
```

The overarching error is:

```
$ grass
Starting GRASS GIS...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/grass74/gui/wxpython/core/globalvar.py", line 86, in CheckForWx
    import wxversion
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wxversion'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/grass74/gui/wxpython/core/globalvar.py", line 89, in CheckForWx
    import wx
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wx'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/grass74/gui/wxpython/gis_set.py", line 31, in <module>
    from core import globalvar
  File "/usr/lib/grass74/gui/wxpython/core/globalvar.py", line 116, in <module>
    CheckForWx()
  File "/usr/lib/grass74/gui/wxpython/core/globalvar.py", line 103, in CheckForWx
    print >> sys.stderr, 'ERROR: wxGUI requires wxPython. %s' % str(e)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'builtin_function_or_method' and '_io.TextIOWrapper'. Did you mean "print(<message>, file=<output_stream>)"?
ERROR: Error in GUI startup. See messages above (if any) and if necessary, please report this error to the GRASS developers.
On systems with package manager, make sure you have the right GUI package, probably named grass-gui, installed.
To run GRASS GIS in text mode use the -text flag.
Use '--help' for further options
     grass74 --help
See also: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/helptext.html
Exiting...
```

And when I follow the gui instructions:

```
$ grass74 -gui
Starting GRASS GIS...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/grass74/gui/wxpython/core/globalvar.py", line 86, in CheckForWx
    import wxversion
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wxversion'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/grass74/gui/wxpython/core/globalvar.py", line 89, in CheckForWx
    import wx
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wx'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/grass74/gui/wxpython/gis_set.py", line 31, in <module>
    from core import globalvar
  File "/usr/lib/grass74/gui/wxpython/core/globalvar.py", line 116, in <module>
    CheckForWx()
  File "/usr/lib/grass74/gui/wxpython/core/globalvar.py", line 103, in CheckForWx
    print >> sys.stderr, 'ERROR: wxGUI requires wxPython. %s' % str(e)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'builtin_function_or_method' and '_io.TextIOWrapper'. Did you mean "print(<message>, file=<output_stream>)"?
ERROR: Error in GUI startup. See messages above (if any) and if necessary, please report this error to the GRASS developers.
On systems with package manager, make sure you have the right GUI package, probably named grass-gui, installed.
To run GRASS GIS in text mode use the -text flag.
Use '--help' for further options
     grass74 --help
See also: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/helptext.html
Exiting...
```

I have grass-core, grass-gui, grass-dev, wx3.0-headers, wxsqlite3-3.0-dbg 
and wxcommon installed.

What's happening?

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that the python interpreter used for running grass has not installed the wxPython package.

For solving it, you could create a python environment (Conda or env), activate it and install packages required for grass (essential ones are wxpython and numpy).

```
conda create -n grass_env python=3
conda activate grass_env
conda install wxpython
conda install numpy
```

Then, over this environment run `grass`. Every time you want to run grass you must activate this environment `conda activate grass_env`.